# Need to clear import/module path for python interpreter

Tags: python, unix, module, import

I need a unix terminal command that will boot a python interpreter without giving it access to import anything. I am aware that you can import os, and then change that path, but this would be counter productive, so I need to do it either on Python startup, or without importing anything in the python interpreter.

Comment: That's odd. Why would you do that? You can use `virtualenv` to create new environment for working with `python` and I don't think there is a way to do what you want, so probably `virtualenv` is a closest approach to what you need.

Comment: I think it's more about not giving users the access to important things. Also I doubt changing something in the ``os`` module does what you say.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have robust support for running untrusted code, but for a reasonable approximation, you can try [this blog post](http://tav.espians.com/paving-the-way-to-securing-the-python-interpreter.html).  A more robust alternative would be to use Lua, JavaScript or TCL, all of which are carefully designed to run untrusted code in a crafted sandbox environment.

Comment: Here's the sandboxing intro directly from PyPy:
http://pypy.org/features.html#sandboxing